# Taking sentences with a spatial factor

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

To ask my question precisely, I should say that I have got many terms, among them some have coefficients $M^n$. Some things like :
$$f = f_1(M) + f_2(M) + M f_3(M)+ M^2 f_4(M)+f_5(M)+...$$. I need to tackle the terms that have $M^n$ in their coefficients. If I write:
$$termswithoutM=f-(f/.M \rightarrow 0)$$ and then:
$$termswithM = f - (termswithoutM)$$. As you see, this clearly does not work because taking $M$ to be zero affects f_i's. How I can take just terms with the $M^n$ coefficient?
Part of my code:
$$...-\frac{K_z^3 M^2 U \sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} J_{M-3}\left(\sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} \rho \right) \sin (-(M-2) \phi +t \omega -\text{$\mathcal{K}$z} z)}{4 \rho ^2 \omega ^2}+\frac{K_z M^2 U \sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} J_{M-3}\left(\sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} \rho \right) \sin (-(M-2) \phi +t \omega -K_z z)}{4 \rho ^2}+\frac{K_z^3 M U \sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} J_{M-3}\left(\sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} \rho \right) \sin (-(M-2) \phi +t \omega -K_z z)}{\rho ^2 \omega ^2}-\frac{5 K_z^3 U \sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} J_{M-3}\left(\sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} \rho \right) \sin (-(M-2) \phi +t \omega -K_z z)}{4 \rho ^2 \omega ^2}-\frac{5 K_z^2 U \sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} J_{M-3}\left(\sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} \rho \right) \sin (-(M-2) \phi+t \omega -K_z z)}{4 \rho ^2 \omega }+\frac{K_z M U \sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} J_{M-3}\left(\sqrt{\omega ^2-K_z^2} \rho \right) \sin (-(M-2) \phi +t \omega -K_z z)}{\rho ^2}+....$$
I can not simplify the whole, so I want to trick, because when $M$ is zero I can simplify.

Comment: Please include copy-paste-able Mathematica code to make the question more concrete.

Comment: @Syed, the actual terms are too long.

Comment: Present a minimal example that is representative enough to model your problem. How about a 4th degree polynomial in `M`?

Comment: @Syed, the power of M in the coefficients are 0,1,2,3.There is no $M^4$.

Comment: Can you not make a MWE using Mathematica code to illustrate the problem? Showing what the desired expression should look like afterwords?

Comment: Try:  `f /. x1_  _[M] /; ! FreeQ[x1, M] -> 0`

Comment: Something like `CoefficientList[f1[M]+f2[M]+M f3[M]+M^2 f4[M]+f5[M],M][[2]]`?

Comment: Or (with `poly` defined as in the last comment) `Plus@@Cases[poly,M^2_]`?

Comment: @Nasser, I have done.

Comment: To build on the comment by @Adam, `(Flatten[CoefficientList[f1[M] + f2[M] + M f3[M] + M^2 f4[M] + f5[M],  M]] /. M -> 0) . {1, M, M^2}` solves your problem, if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The TeX you posted is weird for a few reasons

- there's $t()$ and $z()$
- there's $z$ multiplied by $\text{z}$; I'm taking these to be different variables

Regardless, it was quick to write in Mathematica

```
poly=-((\[ScriptCapitalK] z^3 M^2 U Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] Subscript[J, 
M - 3] (Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
  z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] \[Rho]) Sin[(2 - M) \[Phi] + 
 t \[Omega] - \[ScriptCapitalK] z \[GothicZ]])/(
4 \[Omega]^2 \[Rho]^2)) + (\[ScriptCapitalK] z M^2 U \
Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] Subscript[J, 
M - 3] (Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
 z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] \[Rho]) Sin[(2 - M) \[Phi] + 
t \[Omega] - \[ScriptCapitalK] z \[GothicZ]])/(
4 \[Rho]^2) + (\[ScriptCapitalK] z^3 M U Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] Subscript[J, 
M - 3] (Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
 z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] \[Rho]) Sin[(2 - M) \[Phi] + 
t \[Omega] - \[ScriptCapitalK] z \[GothicZ]])/(\[Omega]^2 \
\[Rho]^2) - (\[ScriptCapitalK] z^3 U Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] Subscript[J, 
M - 3] (Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
 z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] \[Rho]) Sin[(2 - M) \[Phi] + 
t \[Omega] - \[ScriptCapitalK] z \[GothicZ]])/(
4 \[Omega]^2 \[Rho]^2) - (
5 \[ScriptCapitalK] z^2 U Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]]
Subscript[J, 
M - 3] (Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
 z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] \[Rho]) Sin[(2 - M) \[Phi] + 
t \[Omega] - \[ScriptCapitalK] z \[GothicZ]])/(
4 \[Omega] \[Rho]^2) + (\[ScriptCapitalK] z M U Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] Subscript[J, 
M - 3] (Sqrt[\[Omega]^2 - 
 z^2 \[ScriptCapitalK]] \[Rho]) Sin[(2 - M) \[Phi] + 
t \[Omega] - \[ScriptCapitalK] z \[GothicZ]])/\[Rho]
```

It only looks so long because of all the `\[ScriptCapitalK]`s and `\[Omega]`s etc.  Now `CoefficientList[poly,M]` indeed produces a list with the proper coefficients.  You can see it another way with

```
Plus @@ Join[
Cases[poly, ((p : M^_) | Times[a__, p : M^_]) :> a Style[p, Red]], 
Cases[poly, (M | Times[a__, M]) -> a Style[M, Darker@Green]], 
Cases[poly, a : HoldPattern@Times[Except[M | M^_] ..] -> a]]
```

[image: colored]

Be careful: that last code with the `Cases` can break and miss terms in your expression.

Maybe you should ask a new question about writing or simplifying your code.  How did you arrive at the expression?

Comment: Excuse me. I did my best to make it more clear.

Comment: Can you type your new expression in Mathematica?